# Bayesian Methods for Causal Inference with Observational Panel Data

Tags: bayesian, panel-data, causality

How comprehensive is the toolkit for Bayesian inference when trying to make causal inferences with observational panel data?

I can see an easy application with the incorporation of fixed effects or the ADL model, but these models have well-documented problems.

I also understand that there are Bayesian applications for difference-in-differences and synthetic controls, but each methods are generally suited for very particular designs (parallel trends for DID, one/few treated units for synthetic control, one (preferably) time period of treatment for both, etc.)

Two methods that I have grown fond of are panel matching and marginal structural models. However, the developers of the {PanelMatch} package, to my knowledge, have not implemented a Bayesian framework for their methodology. In addition, it seems the development of a Bayesian marginal structural model is in the [works](https://github.com/ajnafa/Latent-Bayesian-MSM/tree/main), but is not yet complete.

Say that I have N > 50 units and T > 20 time periods where treatment statuses can change over time, there is no initial timing when treatment is assigned to all treated units, and I want to operate under a Bayesian framework to attempt to estimate a causal effect of treatment. What would one do under this scenario?

Comment: This actually seems to be a question about the existence of software to perform Bayesian inference - (what we call "causal inference" is a matter of assumptions). Questions about software are off topic. Performing Bayesian inference with matching, weighting, and adjustment to block confounding effects is relatively straightforward with a little thought.

Comment: @AdamO In the context of panel data, traditional matching, weighting, and regression adjustment are inappropriate and will often yield biased effects (Blackwell 2018, Imai et al. 2021). Estimators like panel matching or MSMs are a way to extend familiar matching/weighting frameworks to the panel context, but, as you noticed, to my knowledge, no such software exists yet to meld these panel estimators with Bayesian inference. I was wondering how Bayesian researchers working with observational panel data deal with this apparent lack of software support.

Comment: I don't want to get into the pedantics, but the point is that your question has several missing pieces and it's not up to us to fit them back together. You are asking about a Bayesian "toolkit" - so do you mean software? Either way, you shouldn't expect to see a corresponding Bayesian analogue for every single frequentist procedure. Sometimes you motivate a model, and clarify which parameters (possibly all) are parametrized with a prior, then Bayesian inference is simply how you employ the decision rule.

Comment: I feel like my question is fairly intuitive and sufficient. I work with observational panel data regularly. Such data is often not generated from a process where one can assume that repeated sampling generates the data. As such, it is natural for me to ask about corresponding Bayesian methods as such inference is often more appropriate. There is nothing about panel matching estimates that are inherently frequentist (although, the paper I referenced for MSMs highlights the complications of propensity scores for Bayesian analysis). There is a clear application here, in my opinion.

Comment: @AdamO if questions about statistical software are off-topic in stats, perhaps we should inform the [Journal of Statistical Software](https://www.jstatsoft.org/index) and [Computo](https://computo.sfds.asso.fr/) that they may want to cease operation or switch fields...

Comment: @Scriddie you can read the site rules yourself. If they're not clear, post to meta for clarification. If you think you can edit the question to a salvageable form, then do so and nominate to reopen. I'd be glad to vote for reopen if I understood the edited version.